# Inspect cookies using Perl

Tags: perl, http, cookies

I've written a short Perl script that lists the current cookies for the website, but somehow it reports the cookie's `domain` and `expires` empty. **What am I doing wrong or am I misunderstanding the mechanics behind cookies?**

My ultimate goal is to be able to delete exsisting cookies with a button.

The script is live [here](http://blog.linformatronics.nl/cookies.pl), but it may help if you visit my [blog](http://blog.linformatronics.nl/) first so there are actually some cookies set. Here is my source code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI::Cookie;

my $table;
my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
if ( keys %cookies ) {
        $table .= "<table border=\"3\" cellpadding=\"5\">";
        $table .= "<caption>COOKIES</caption>";
        $table .= "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Domain</th><th>Path</th><th>Expires</th>
                   <th align=\"left\">Value</th></tr>";
        foreach my $cookie ( keys %cookies ) {
                $table .= "<tr>";
                $table .= "<td>$cookie</td>";
                $table .= "<td>" . $cookies{ $cookie }->domain() . "</td>";
                $table .= "<td>" . $cookies{ $cookie }->path . "</td>";
                $table .= "<td>" . $cookies{ $cookie }->expires . "</td>";
                $table .= "<td>" . $cookies{ $cookie }->value . "</td>";
                $table .= "</tr>";
        }
        $table .= "</table>";
}

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<head></head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "$table";
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

Regardless the various cookies on various websites where I install the script, the output looks like this and Domain and Expires is always empty:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                   
| Name          | Domain | Path | Expires | Value                                         |                   
|---------------+--------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------|
| bb2_screener_ |        | /    |         | 1379007156 2001:980:1b7f:1:a00:27ff:fea6:a2e7 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers does not provide any meta information to the server about the cookies they send. There isn't even a way for them to send it. What the browser sends looks like the following:

```
Cookie: a=b; c=d; e=f
```

Comment: To expand on @ikegami's answer, the `domain` and `expires` fields are there for your program to *set* cookies, and the client will use that information when deciding what cookies to send back to the server. But that information is not sent back - only the names and values are.

Comment: So much for my idea to create a script where I can delete cookies I guess. Can I access domain information from a javascript (as in is it worth Google'ing for that?), because that is really the missing link to reach my goal.

Comment: I don't know. Possibly, but only for the cookies for the domain and path of the document containing the JS.

Comment: You can't delete cookies from other domains because the client will not send them back to your script. You can't use JavaScript to manipulate cookies from other domains because the JavaScript environment will enforce the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: They are browser plugins to help you manage your cookies (e.g. "Web Developer" for FF allows to view/add/delete)

Comment: I was hoping to create a simple script to assist in configuring/testing a single sign in "application". Simply a web page to surf to and click the delete button for a particular cookie (under test) and to be able to inspect expiry time/date per cookie. I had hoped not to need a plugin because that is making things more complicated for the team members to work on the issue. I guess I have little options.

Comment: @jippie, yeah, it looks like you can't read it from JS either. Selenium gives you all but the expiry date.